# bad kerning of italics in beamer

Tags: beamer, kerning

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  ``Here is text that ends in \emph{italics!}''
  \bigskip

  ``Here is text that ends in \emph{italics!}\kern1.5pt''
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad kerning of italics in beamer]

Is this a bug? Is there a better fix than manually adjusting the spacing around the inverted commas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a “feature” due to how `\emph` is redefined in `beamer`. In `beamerbaseoverlay` we find

```
\newcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\itshape}#1}}

\mode
<article>
{
  \renewcommand<>{\emph}{\only#1{\beameroriginal\emph}}
}
```

which means that in presentation mode doing `\emph{abc}` is the same as `{\itshape abc}`, so the italic correction is not automatically added at the end. Quite strangely, the redefinitions of `\textit` and similar commands are

```
\mode
<all>
{
  \renewcommand<>{\textbf}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\textbf}}}
  \renewcommand<>{\textit}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\textit}}}
  \renewcommand<>{\textsl}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\textsl}}}
  \renewcommand<>{\textsf}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\textsf}}}
  \renewcommand<>{\textrm}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\textrm}}}
}
```

There must be a reason for this difference, but I can think to none.

You have two choices: either use `\textit` or hack `beamer` into making it use a proper redefinition of `\emph`.

Here's an example:

```
\let\origemph\emph
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewcommand<>{\origemph}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\origemph}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
``Here is text that ends in \emph{italics!}'' (\texttt{\string\emph})

\medskip

``Here is text that ends in \textit{italics!}'' (\texttt{\string\textit})

\medskip

``Here is text that ends in \origemph{italics!}'' (\texttt{\string\origemph})
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I used `\origemph` in order to show what happens: if I save the meaning of `\emph` before `beamer` enters into action and then use the same method as with `\textit` for redefining it, it works as expected. Indeed, note that `\textit` inserts the italic correction.

[image]

How could a hack for being able to type `\emph` and not `\origemph` in that way?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% redefine \emph to be as in the kernel
\expandafter\def\expandafter\emph\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\protect\csname emph \endcsname
}
% now redefine it to be overlay aware
\renewcommand<>{\emph}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\emph}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
``Here is text that ends in \emph{italics!}'' (\texttt{\string\emph})

\medskip

``Here is text that ends in \textit{italics!}'' (\texttt{\string\textit})
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if anyone can help explain why `\emph` is treated differently from other shapeshifting commands...

Comment: @Seamus Don't ask me!